# Is there some way to check that I am using "easy language" for beginners?

Tags: technology

When writing texts intended for beginners, I'd like to avoid complicated language and I'd like to make sure I don't use (too many?) correlatives. Is there a computer program or other resource one can use to check?

Comment: I would recommend looking at the first section of the Esperanto course on Duolingo and base your texts around that vocabulary. New learners will almost certainly be using Duolingo so they would benefit from having something simple to practice their new vocabulary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ne estas multaj programoj por kontroli la facilecon de iu teksto. Ne ĉiuj konsentas pri tio kio estas facila. Tamen homoj konsentas ke oftaj vortoj estas pli facile kompreneblaj ol maloftaj vortoj. Por kontroli tion, estas la programo kiu nomiĝas [Facililo](https://legoscia.github.io/facililo/). La retejo indikos al vi se vorto de via teksto ne apartenas al la [vortolisto de Kontakto](http://remush.be/tezauro/Kontakto.html). (Kontakto estas revuo kun kelkaj artikoloj en facila Esperanto.)

Ekster la demando, se vi volas scii kiel skribi artikolon en facila Esperanto, mi konsilas al vi legi ĉi tiun artikolon de la Instituto Fina Venko : [Kiel verki facilajn artikolojn](http://finavenko.net/kiel-verki-facilajn-artikolojn/).

Comment: Strange... evidente "ĝi" ne estas en la vortlisto.

Comment: @kristan: La pronomoj aperas en aparta listo antaŭ la ĉefa listo kun radikoj. Kompreneble "ĝi" aperas en la listo.

Comment: Ne estas ĝuste diri, ke Kontakto estas revuo en facila Esperanto. Ĝi enhavas unuopajn artikolojn en facila Esperanto, sed ĝiaj plej multaj artikoloj estas en normala lingvaĵo.

Comment: @MarcosCramer Bone, estas nur ke en tiu programo Facililo, la vorto "ĝi" estas ruĝe markita, kiel "ne en la listo". Se pronomoj estas en aparta listo, tio klarigas la aferon.

Answer (score 4):

"Facililo" shows in green the most frequently used words in the list. It shows in blue the other words in the list. It shows in red the words that are not in the list.

La vortolisto estis kreita de Anna Löwenstein por la kunlaborantoj al la revuo Kontakto, kiuj skribas en facilan Esperanton por komencantoj. Ĝi havas 1000 vortojn. (This paragraph copied from the list)

The word list was created by Anna Löwenstein for the collaborators to the magazine "Kontakto", which is written in easy Esperanto for beginners. It has 1,000 words.

"Esperantilo" is an editor; converts cx to ĉ; checks spelling.

"Lingvoilo" will check the grammar and the spelling for Esperanto, and many other languages.

The links to these applications are here: http://esperantofre.com/edu/lernia.htm#skri